# Get transition probability, emission(output) probability, and initial probability from hmm nltk

Tags: python, nltk, probability, hidden-markov-models

I have successfully implementing hidden markov model for pos tagging with library from NLTK HMM Tagger and now I want to know every probability that was used in the tagging process for every word,tag. From what I read there are transition probability, emission probability, initial start probability, and probability of the tag. How to get those probability?

I searched the internet and can't find it. I want validate the tagging result with my own calculation and it is too many if i count one by one every word and tag probability because the size of my corpus is big.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using the class `HiddenMarkovModelTagger` in NLTK 3.3.

You can see the source [here](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/hmm.html).

Using this, we can see that there are the following fields in the object:

```
def __init__(self, symbols, states, transitions, outputs, priors, transform=_identity):
        self._symbols = unique_list(symbols)
        self._states = unique_list(states)
        self._transitions = transitions
        self._outputs = outputs
        self._priors = priors
        self._cache = None
        self._transform = transform
```

This is probably the solution to your problem.